# Access Control List (ACL) in SAPUI5 application

Tags: javascript, web, sapui5, acl, access-control

I am currently working on an application based on SAPUI5 and I am facing a task of creating some kind of ACL.

The authentication is made beyond the application (the user is already authenticated, with some profile/user data which can be accessed globally). The idea is to create an additional data attribute indicating the user role: let's say - "user" and "superuser".

Based on the role, the user would have access to certain views/routes and/or methods on certain controllers (responsible for CRUD operations).

One idea would be creating a globally accessed model attached to:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myACL");
```

and then accessed by:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("myACL").getData();
```

What's the best approach of creating a well working ACL in SAPUI5? Is there some kind of built-in mechanism responsible for creating a controller/route/view/method-wise ACL? What would be the best practices in creating such an ACL? The application has only three controllers at the moment, full refactor is also an option, so any hints would be very appreciated.

Comment: SAPUI5 does not have any built-in Access control mechanism. You may have to build this yourself. Access control on the client-side might not really be a good choice, just my 2 cents

Comment: Access control should certainly be done on the server for security. But access control on the client side, if done properly, can also greatly enhance the user experience: no need to present the user with links to parts of the application he doesn't have access to for instance.